# Is it possible to get metadata (specifically the original creation date or time) from a .pdf that was emailed to me as an attachment?

Tags: metadata, attachment

I have a .pdf attachment that was emailed to me (not shared via google drive or anything) and I was wondering if it was possible to find out the date and/or time it was originally created? Everything I've tried to date just gives me the date/time that I download the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ExifTool](https://ExifTool.org), you could run this command to see all the time based tags embedded in the file
`exiftool -time:all -G1 -a -s /path/to/file/`

But take note that metadata is easily alterable.